# Any way to change names for auto-created views by kotlin-extensions?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm new in Kotlin. I've red https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html and noticed that views can be auto-binded to activity via importing 
`kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*.`

If I declaring view with id = "btn_login" in Activity I can access to it via

```
activity.btn_login.setText("Login")
```

But. Is there any way to change alias to view, such as ButterKnife does :

```
@BindView(<id of view>)
<name of view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a synthetic import, so technically you can use an import alias to call it by another name:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.btn_login as btnLogin
```

But considering there is no tool that does this automatically, you might want to just embrace a different ID naming scheme.

Here's a reasonable one:

> **What-Where-Description-Modifier:**
>
> `recyclerSearchSuggestions` - RecyclerView showing search suggestions
>
> `fabSearchGo` - FloatingActionButton that executes a search
>
> `textSearchFilterChip` - TextView that represents search filters, styled as a material chip
>
> `buttonSearchClearFilter` - Button that clears selected filter chips
>
> `editSearchFilter` - EditText used to narrow down search suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can, as far as I know, is by using named imports. This is a really nice feature of the Kotlin language, that Java doesn't support. Unfortunately, this requires manually setting it for those you want to replace, so it can be slightly boilerplate.

But you can change your import to:

```
import kotlinx.android...your_view as yourView
```

This applies to any and all imports, and any types too. It could be done with classes, methods, constants... Whatever you feel like.

Although if you can access the XML files, I recommend you just change the IDs in there. There's no reason not to use camelCase anyways, and it's slightly easier than using `as customName` in every import.

Comment: Thing is, sometimes I'd like to use an id that is something like "local" to current activity. If I use this local id in XML, it can clash with other IDs in other layouts. In this case it would be great to have such option.